# Async task child process parallelized

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

My application has a button "run task".
When i touch it, a "main async task" is started.
The "main async task", in doInBackground method, starts 10 new (different) child AsyncTask.
My problem is that all child processes are not run in parallel.
To run every AsyncTask i've used executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).
That is not working, every child asynctask are run sequentially.

I've also tried to create and run the cihld asnyctask in the main ui thread (using .getActivity().runOnUiThread), it has not worked too.

So my question is: how can i achive my goal? I need all child asynctask to be run in parallel.

EDIT:

```
public class ATask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  ...
}
public class BTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  ...
}
public class CTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  ...
}
public class DTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  ...
}

public class AsyncCoreTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    new ATask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    new BTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    new CTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    new DTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    return null;
  }
}

public class MainThreadFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
  new AsyncCoreTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
  ...
}
```

Expected: main thread runs asyncCoreTask and then asyncCoretask runs in parallel ATask, BTask, CTask, DTask.
Actual: main thread runs asnycCoreTask, and then asyncCoreTask runs ATask, when ATask ends BTask starts, when BTask ends CTask runs and so on

Comment: Try creating your own thread pool - since api 11 the thread_pool_executor executes in serial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning tasks to a thread pool like AsyncTaskExecutor, they will not run serially. Must be parallel. Maybe you have short tasks that are getting terminated one after the other before the scheduler does a switch.

You can also try Completable Future for tasks chaining.

If you share proper code, I can correct it out.